# C# Searching MongoDB string that starts with "xyz"

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try to code a Storagesystem and i got one Problem and dont know how to solve it...

```
       public static List<string> GetAllItemsFromDB(string Searchbar)
        {
            List<string> retList = new List<string>();

            retList.Clear();

            var filter = Builders<DB_Package_Item>.Filter.Eq(Item => Item.Item_Name, Searchbar);

            var ItemsMatch = Item_DB.Find(filter).ToList();

           foreach (var Item in ItemsMatch.ToList())
            {
                retList.Add(Item.Item_Name);
            }

            return retList;
        }
```

This Works. But when i change the filter to:

`var filter = Builders<DB_Package_Item>.Filter.ElemMatch(Item => Item.Item_Name, Searchbar);`

It crasches as soon i type any char in the searchbar with Error code : "System.InvalidOperationException: "The serializer for field 'Item_Name' must implement IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serialization info."
"

I just dont get it why...

This is the Data_Package for MongoDB

```
public class DB_Package_Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Item_ID { get; set; }
        public int Box_ID { get; set; }
        public string Item_Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Partnumber { get; set; }
        public string Supplier { get; set; }
    }
```

Thx for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`FilterDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>.ElemMatch<TItem>`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_ElemMatch__1_1.htm) or `$elemMatch` operator is for searching the item in the array field, which is not appropriate for your scenario to search (term) for a string field.

You need the [`$regex`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator which is [`FilterDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>.Regex`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Regex_1.htm) in C# syntax.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var filter = Builders<DB_Package_Item>.Filter.Regex(Item => Item.Item_Name
    , new Regex("^" + Searchbar));
```

For case-insensitive:

```cs
new Regex("^" + Searchbar, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

---

Or

```cs
var filter = Builders<DB_Package_Item>.Filter.Regex(Item => Item.Item_Name
    , new BsonRegularExpression("^" + Searchbar));
```

For case-insensitive,

```cs
new BsonRegularExpression("^" + Searchbar, "i")
```

Comment: Okay that sounds very good. but one queston...  i know its stupid but the "^" for what is that? and can i put it together with the string var "searchbar"? like("^" + searchbar));

Comment: `^` in regex means start with. Yes, so you need to append `^` in front of `Searchbar`.